# Expanding Summation with terms

Tags: summation, series-expansion

I'm trying to expand this series:

```
Sum[(Binomial[n - 1, k]*(-1)^k*(θ/T)^(n - 1 - k))/
     (m - (k + 1)*α), {k, 0, n - 1}]
```

to look something like this:

```
1/(m - 5 α) - (4 (θ/T)^α)/(m - 4 α) + (6 (θ/T)^(2 α))/(m - 3 α) - 
  (4 (θ/T)^(3 α))/(m - 2 α) + (θ/T)^(4 α)/(m - α)
```

But I keep getting things like this..

```
(-2 m^3 α (5 T - 7 θ) (T - θ)^3 + m^4 (T - θ)^4 + 
  m^2 α^2 (T - θ)^2 (35 T^2 - 94 T θ + 71 θ^2) + 
  24 α^4 (T^4 - 5 T^3 θ + 10 T^2 θ^2 - 10 T θ^3 + 5 θ^4) - 
  2 m α^3 (25 T^4 - 122 T^3 θ + 234 T^2 θ^2 - 
  214 T θ^3 + 77 θ^4))/(T^4 (m - 5 α) (m - 4 α) 
  (m - 3 α) (m - 2 α) (m - α))
```

So, how expand summation to look more like

```
1/(m - 5 α) - (4 (θ/T)^α)/(m - 4 α) + (6 (θ/T)^(2 α))/(m - 3 α) - 
  (4 (θ/T)^(3 α))/(m - 2 α) + (θ/T)^(4 α)/(m - α)
```

Also, how can I format code in here better when I ask questions?

Comment: See [`How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site`](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1585/9362)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I get the symbols like "Sigma" - I.e., have it look just like in my notebook...

Comment: The object should be to make it easy for others to copy and paste your code so that they can provide help--not to make it look like your notebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you're trying as you didn't include that, but on my system:

```
n = 5;

Sum[(Binomial[n - 1, k]*(-1)^k*(θ/T)^(n - 1 - k))/(m - (k + 1)*α), {k, 0, n - 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Really? I just ran the same command on my system and put it in a closed form expression - the Hypergeometric Function 2F1...Wierd...What do you think is going on?

Comment: Never mind the previous comment...Sorry...I'm kind of new to Mathematica stuff...When I type i "n = 5", and input it, then this works...